# How configure routing for each section that it have his own menu

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular2-routing

I'm developing a business application, which has several "sections" such as sales, purchases, stock, etc. Each of these sections has its own menu, the entire application starts from the login form, then the user chooses the section that he / she wants and then the menu of the chosen section is shown.

This application I am developing using Angular 4 with VSCODE, and I was investigating how to configure the routing theme to be able to have a correct redirection and / or routing for each section. The sections are not mixed, if the user wants to go to another section will have to start with the login.

I have seen that they use routing-modules, other classes with routing, or use only the main module to enter the routes, but it still does not work for me.

I appreciate your help, and some link or example to get to correctly route my application.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow community [**read the asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

[look here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing)

Jus replace Home and About to yours sales, purchases, stock etc. with menu in each. Good luck.